# PDFKit - Last extra blank page added at last of each pdf generated file [NodeJS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, pdf, pdfkit

Last page of each generated PDF file is empty, tried couple of solution didnt work
If I removed createSingleTicket function calling , it still create a single empty page.

I think newPDF.end() might calling immediately but not sure that is the main cause or not, I have tried to move this into Promise but that also didnt work for me

````
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");
const https = require('https');
const readline = require('readline');


const rawTicketFolder = './printTickets/';
const logo = 'images/new-logo@3x.png';
const ticketsFolder = "./ticketsGenerated/";
const chunkSize = 5000;
let downloadedImagePath;

async function processDirectory() {
    const files = await fs.promises.readdir(rawTicketFolder);
    const visibleFiles = files.filter((file) => !file.startsWith('.'));
    for (const file of visibleFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(rawTicketFolder, file);
        const stats = await fs.promises.stat(filePath);
        var folderName = file.slice(0, -4);

        if (!fs.existsSync(ticketsFolder + folderName)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(ticketsFolder + folderName);
        }

        if (stats.isFile()) {
            await processFile(filePath, folderName);
        }
    }
}

async function processFile(filePath, folder) {
    let chunkCounter = 0;
    let lines = [];
    downloadedImagePath = '';
    let isProcessed = false;
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: 'utf8' });
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: readStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });
    // console.log(rl);
    // await downloadImage();
    
    for await (const line of rl) {
            lines.push(line);
            if (lines.length === chunkSize) {
                // console.log(lines);
                await processChunk(JSON.stringify(lines), folder, chunkCounter);
                chunkCounter++;
                lines = [];
                isProcessed = true;
            } else {
                isProcessed = false;
            }
        
    }
    
    if (lines.length > 0 && !isProcessed) {
        // console.log('this');
        await processChunk(JSON.stringify(lines), folder, chunkCounter);
    }
}

function displayProgress(percentage) {
    process.stdout.clearLine();
    process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
    process.stdout.write(`Loading: ${percentage}%`);
}

let counter = 0;
async function processChunk(lines, fol, index) {
    // process the lines in the chunk
    // console.log(lines);
    // printTickets(newArray, filename, folderName);
    var pdf = [];

    console.log('');
    console.log('New Campaign Ticket Generated ' + fol);
    console.log('===================================================');
    
    pdf[counter] = new PDFGenerator({
        size: [110, 140],
        margins: { // by default, all are 72
            top: 14,
            bottom: 7,
            left: 9,
            right: 22
        },
    });

    
        pdf[counter].pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./ticketsGenerated/${fol}/ticket-${fol}-${index+1}.pdf`));
         createSingleTicket(pdf[counter], lines, lines.length);
          console.log(`${counter+1}. File Generated in ./ticketsGenerated/${fol}/ticket-${fol}-${index+1}.pdf`);
          ++counter;
}

async function downloadImage(imagePath) {
    var imageToDownload = JSON.parse(imagePath).lineItem.image.absURL;
    var nameOfImage = imageToDownload.split("/").pop();
    
    https.get(imageToDownload, (res) => {
        
        downloadedImagePath = "downloaded-image-" + nameOfImage;
        const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(downloadedImagePath);

        res.pipe(writeStream);

        writeStream.on("finish", () => {
            writeStream.close();
            $newImage = true;
            console.log('Image Downloaded');
            console.log('===================================================');
            console.log('Generating Tickets ...');
        });
    });

}

async function createSingleTicket(newPDF, ticketDatas, endTicket, ind) {
        const newticketData = JSON.parse(ticketDatas);
        newticketData.forEach((itemData)=> {
            const ticketData = JSON.parse(itemData)
            const prizeTitle = Object.keys(ticketData.lineItem.cashPrice).length > 0 ? ticketData.lineItem.cashPrice.cashCampaignPrice : ticketData.lineItem.productName;
        const customerName = ticketData.customerName;
        const isArabic = checkArabic(ticketData.customerName);
        const purchasedDate = ticketData.creationDate;
        const mobileNumber = ticketData.mobilePhone;
        const ticketNumber = ticketData.ticketNumber;
        var nameOfImage = ticketData.lineItem.image.absURL.split("prize/").pop();
        const productImage = 'downloaded-image-' + nameOfImage;
        // const productImage = '440-LS-00160.png';
        // newPDF.rect(0, 0, newPDF.page.width, newPDF.page.height).fill('#302ed6');
    
        // write text to your file
        newPDF.image(logo, 10, 10, { width: 38 })
        newPDF.image(productImage, 76, 24, { width: 27 });
        newPDF.fontSize(7);
        newPDF.font('Helvetica-Bold').text(prizeTitle, 10, 28, {
            width: 62,
            height: 22,
            lineGap: -1
        });
        newPDF.lineWidth(1);
        newPDF.moveTo(0, 47).lineTo(110, 47).strokeColor('#EDEDED').stroke();
        newPDF.fontSize(5);
        newPDF.font('Helvetica').text('Purchased by', 10, 50);
        if (isArabic) {
            newPDF.fontSize(6);
            newPDF.font('fonts/Cairo-Bold.ttf').text(customerName, 10, 53, {
                width: 92,
                height: 24,
                features: ['rtla'],
                baseline: 'top',
                lineGap: -4,
                align: 'left'
            });
    
        } else {
            newPDF.fontSize(7);
            newPDF.font('Helvetica-Bold').text(customerName, 10, 56, {
                width: 92,
                height: 20,
                lineGap: -1
            });
        }
        newPDF.lineWidth(1);
        newPDF.moveTo(0, 74).lineTo(110, 74).strokeColor('#EDEDED').stroke();
        newPDF.fontSize(5);
        newPDF.font('Helvetica').text('Ticket Number', 10, 78, {
            align: 'left',
            width: 104
        });
        newPDF.fontSize(7);
        newPDF.font('Helvetica-Bold').text(ticketNumber, 10, 84, {
            align: 'left',
            width: 108
        });
    
        newPDF.moveTo(0, 94).lineTo(110, 94).strokeColor('#EDEDED').stroke();
        newPDF.fontSize(5);
        newPDF.font('Helvetica').text('Purchased on', 10, 99, {
            align: 'left',
            width: 108
        });
        newPDF.fontSize(7);
        newPDF.font('Helvetica-Bold').text(purchasedDate, 10, 105, {
            align: 'left',
            width: 108
        });
        newPDF.moveTo(0, 114).lineTo(110, 114).strokeColor('#EDEDED').stroke();
        newPDF.fontSize(5);
        newPDF.font('Helvetica').text('Mobile Number', 10, 118);
    
        newPDF.fontSize(7);
        newPDF.font('Helvetica-Bold').text(mobileNumber, 10, 124);
    
        if (newPDF.y > newPDF.page.margins.bottom && customerName) {
            newPDF.addPage();
          }
        });
        newPDF.end();
    
}

async function checkArabic(str) {
    var arabic = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;
    return arabic.test(str)
}

processDirectory()
  .then(() => console.log('Done'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));```
````